# How to correctly trigger the change of a value in a UserControl using WinForms Data Binding?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, user-controls

I created two `UserControl`s in my WinForms application. One contains a `TextBox` (let's call this `TextEntryControl` for now) and the other one should use the value I entered into this `TextBox` to do internal stuff (enable a button and use the value when this button is clicked) - let's call this `TextUsingControl`.

However, I don't get this right via DataBinding.

**First (naive) approach**

I added a `string` property to `TextEntryControl` like this:

```
public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
```

Then I used the UI designer to bind the `TextBox`'s `Text` property to this `MyStringProperty`, resulting in a `textEntryControlBindingSource`. I added to the constructor right behind the `InitializeComponents()`:

```
textEntryControlBindingSource.Add(this);
```

I added the same property to the `TextUsingControl`, and in my outer UI where I use the two controls, I bound the `TextUsingControl`'s string property to the one of the `TextEntryControl`, and updated the binding source appropriately:

```
textEntryControlBindingSource.Add(textEntryControl1);
```

I use both controls on different tabs of a `TabControl`, and the mechanism only works once, when I first enter text into the text box and then switch to the other control.

**Next try**

I created a simple wrapper class for strings:

```
public sealed class StringWrapper {

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

In my text entry control, I bound the text box to this string wrapper, and changed the property to look like this:

```
public string MyStringProperty {
    get {
        return _stringWrapper.Content;
    }
    set {
        _stringWrapper.Content = value;
    }
}
```

I did a similar thing in the outer control with the `TabControl` - use a `StringWrapper` to bind both `MyStringProperty` of both user controls to.

Result: Same. But this is logical since the outer property that delegates to the wrapper doesn't get notified.

**Third try**

This one works, sort of, but I think this is an ugly workaround.

I ditched the `MyStringProperty` altogether and pass in the wrapper object itself via a property that, again, passes it down to the binding source:

```
public StringWrapper MyStringWrapper {
    get {
        return stringWrapperBindingSource.Cast<StringWrapper>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    set {
        stringWrapperBindingSource.Clear();
        if(value != null) stringWrapperBindingSource.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Now I only create one single `StringWrapper` object and set it to both user controls right after `InitializeComponent()`.

**INotifyPropertyChanged**

As a follow up: I tried `INotifyPropertyChanged` as well as described [on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) This did not help either.

**What I want to achieve**

I want both user controls to have a `MyStringProperty`, and when the text I enter into `TextEntryControl`'s text box changes, the property should update and correctly notify any binding sources it is attached to.
The `TextUsingControl` should update itself when its property changes.

The second half is easy, I just add the appropriate logic into the `set` part of the property, but I am having trouble with the first one.

I am used to Eclipse's JFace Data Binding, where this functionality can be achieved with `PropertyChangeSupport` and `PropertyChangeListener` - here, I just add the appropriate event firing code to the setter and I can use `BeanProperties.value()` when setting up the data binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a combination of a proper property implementation and proper data binding.

**(1) Property implementation:**

The property does not need to be complex. It could be simple type as in your *naïve* approach, but the essential part is that it should provide **property change notification**. You can use the general `INotifyPropertyChanged` mechanism or Windows Forms specific `PropertyNameChanged` named event pattern. In both cases, you cannot use C# **auto property** feature and have to implement it manually (with an explicit backing field). Here is a sample implementation:

```
string myStringProperty;
public string MyStringProperty
{
    get { return myStringProperty; }
    set
    {
        if (myStringProperty == value) return;
        myStringProperty = value;
        var handler = MyStringPropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public event EventHandler MyStringPropertyChanged;
```

**(2) Data binding:**

Binding single control property to a single object property is called simple data binding and is achieved via [Control.DataBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings(v=vs.110).aspx). You can take a look at [ControlBindingsCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlbindingscollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method / [Binding Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.binding(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads and [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx)  class properties/methods/events for more info.

What the `Binding` does is basically creating a link (one or two way) between source object property and target object property. Note the word property - that's exactly what is supported out of the box. But with the following simple helper method (presented in my answer to [How to set Textbox.Enabled from false to true on TextChange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250176/how-to-set-textbox-enabled-from-false-to-true-on-textchange/34250305#34250305)) you can easily create one way expression like binding:

```
public static void Bind(this Control target, string targetProperty, object source, string sourceProperty, Func<object, object> expression)
{
    var binding = new Binding(targetProperty, source, sourceProperty, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
    binding.Format += (sender, e) => e.Value = expression(e.Value);
    target.DataBindings.Add(binding);
}
```

Here is a full working demo:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var splitView = new SplitContainer { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            var textEntry = new TextEntryControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = splitView.Panel1 };
            var textConsumer = new TextConsumingControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = splitView.Panel2 };
            textConsumer.DataBindings.Add("MyStringProperty", textEntry, "MyStringProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }

    class TextEntryControl : UserControl
    {
        TextBox textBox;
        public TextEntryControl()
        {
            textBox = new TextBox { Parent = this, Left = 16, Top = 16 };
            textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "MyStringProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
        }

        string myStringProperty;
        public string MyStringProperty
        {
            get { return myStringProperty; }
            set
            {
                if (myStringProperty == value) return;
                myStringProperty = value;
                var handler = MyStringPropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler MyStringPropertyChanged;
    }

    class TextConsumingControl : UserControl
    {
        Button button;
        public TextConsumingControl()
        {
            button = new Button { Parent = this, Left = 16, Top = 16, Text = "Click Me" };
            button.Bind("Enabled", this, "MyStringProperty", value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string));
        }

        string myStringProperty;
        public string MyStringProperty
        {
            get { return myStringProperty; }
            set
            {
                if (myStringProperty == value) return;
                myStringProperty = value;
                var handler = MyStringPropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler MyStringPropertyChanged;
    }

    public static class BindingUtils
    {
        public static void Bind(this Control target, string targetProperty, object source, string sourceProperty, Func<object, object> expression)
        {
            var binding = new Binding(targetProperty, source, sourceProperty, true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
            binding.Format += (sender, e) => e.Value = expression(e.Value);
            target.DataBindings.Add(binding);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the requested (one way) binding between `textEntry` and `textConsumer` is established with this single line:

```
textConsumer.DataBindings.Add("MyStringProperty", textEntry, "MyStringProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never);
```

Another interesting point you can see in the demo is that if you wish, you can actually data bind internal control properties too. The whole synchronization between the `TextEntryControl` internal text box and the property is achieved with this single line:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "MyStringProperty", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

and the `TextConsumingControl` internal button enabling:

```
button.Bind("Enabled", this, "MyStringProperty", value => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string));
```

Of course the last two things are optional, you can do that in the property setter, but it's kind of cool to know that such option exists.